# npm is not updated in mac

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am using ios and installed `npm` few days back. Its current version is 5.6.0. Now, I want to update `npm`.

I am using the following steps to update `npm`:

- I opened the terminal, wrote `npm -v` into terminal and looked into the current version of `npm` with is 5.6.0  as for now.
- Then, I wrote `npm update -g` in terminal to update the current version of `npm` but it is showing the following error:

> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri

Comment: try with sudo `sudo npm update -g`

Comment: Use https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: thanks it is updated now current version is 5.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob,

Go to your root

Run which npm and see the root, I believe it will be "/usr/local/bin/npm"

Stay on your root and try to run `npm install -g npm@lates`t

I bet you get "missing permissions..."

Stay on your root and run the command: (to give permissions) `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

And then run: `npm install -g npm@latest`

Now it should work, please try to run npm -v and see if it changed.

Goodluck :)